# How to get data from JSON using Axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, gatsby

This is my first stab at Gatsby and Axios in order to get some json from an API.

Basically, I'm trying to retrieve some json data from this json file:

```
{
"filters": {},
"competition": {
    "id": 2019,
    "area": {
        "id": 2114,
        "name": "Italy"
    },
    "name": "Serie A",
    "code": "SA",
    "plan": "TIER_ONE",
    "lastUpdated": "2018-10-08T15:10:08Z"
},
"season": {
    "id": 290,
    "startDate": "2018-08-18",
    "endDate": "2019-05-26",
    "currentMatchday": 9,
    "winner": null
},
"standings": [
    {
        "stage": "REGULAR_SEASON",
        "type": "TOTAL",
        "group": null,
        "table": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "team": {
                    "id": 109,
                    "name": "Juventus FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/d2/Juventus_Turin.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 8,
                "won": 8,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 24,
                "goalsFor": 18,
                "goalsAgainst": 5,
                "goalDifference": 13
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

Here is my what I'm using to map the data:

```
team.data.standings.map((team, i) => {
const standingsNode = {
id: `${i}`,
parent: `__SOURCE__`,
internal: {
  type: `Season`,
},
children: [],

stage: team.stage,
type: team.type,
}

 const contentDigest = crypto
.createHash(`md5`)
.update(JSON.stringify(standingsNode))
.digest(`hex`);
standingsNode.internal.contentDigest = contentDigest;

createNode(standingsNode);
});
```

My question is, how do I map the "table" child of "standings" in my code?
When I try to query in GraphiQL I can't seem to be able to drill down to the table data, I can only fetch stage and type from the json data (see below image)

[GraphiQL example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n5fX.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
team.data.standings.map((team, i) => {
```

to

```
team.data.standings[0].table.map((team, i) => {
```

or use two maps.

Comment: Ok this got me one step closer, I can now retrieve the total number of "table" objects but I still can't be able to pull the team id, name, and crestUrl
[See GraphiQL Image](https://imgur.com/wYbTMia)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead of accessing table with index position

```
team.data.standings.map((team, i) => {
    team.table.map((t, index) => {

    });
});
```

Comment: How would the rest of my map look like?
Here is how I tried (https://gist.github.com/vibrains/b6b6fbde3cbbadecbcce10825077dcf8) (which is not working)

Comment: What is not working? One thing I noticed in your code which is not correct. You are assigning object to id. What if you want to assign? If you want to assign team id then it should be t.team.id but not just t

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how you want this data, as I am not that experienced with GraphQL, however as mentioned above, you need to use a second map. The standings table is actually an array. 
See the code below:

```js
let team = {
    "filters": {},
    "competition": {
        "id": 2019,
        "area": {
            "id": 2114,
            "name": "Italy"
        },
        "name": "Serie A",
        "code": "SA",
        "plan": "TIER_ONE",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-10-08T15:10:08Z"
    },
    "season": {
        "id": 290,
        "startDate": "2018-08-18",
        "endDate": "2019-05-26",
        "currentMatchday": 9,
        "winner": null
    },
    "standings": [
        {
            "stage": "REGULAR_SEASON",
            "type": "TOTAL",
            "group": null,
            "table": [
                {
                    "position": 1,
                    "team": {
                        "id": 109,
                        "name": "Juventus FC",
                        "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/d2/Juventus_Turin.svg"
                    },
                    "playedGames": 8,
                    "won": 8,
                    "draw": 0,
                    "lost": 0,
                    "points": 24,
                    "goalsFor": 18,
                    "goalsAgainst": 5,
                    "goalDifference": 13
                }
           ]
         }
       ]
    }

let teamData = team.standings.map((team, i) => {
     const standingsNode = {
        id: `${i}`,
        parent: `__SOURCE__`,
        internal: {
          type: `Season`,
        },
        children: [],
        
        stage: team.stage,
        type: team.type,
        table: team.table.map(data=>{
        return {
            position: data.position,
            team: data.team.name,
            crestUrl: data.team.crestUrl

        };
    })
        
            
        
        }
     return standingsNode;
       });
console.log(teamData);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, using 2 maps is working as far as seeing the standings in GraphiQL.
Now, how do I map the team name and crestURL in the second map?
Would I do something like this?
`table: team.table.map(data=>{
      position: data.position
      team: data.team.name
    })`